# Undefined Reference issues using Semaphores

Tags: c, semaphore, undefined-reference

I am playing around with using Semaphores, but I keep encountering Undefined Reference warnings, thus causing my code not to work. I pulled example code from a text, but was having issues with some of their syntax, so I went to POSIX's semaphore tutorial and changed things around to their syntax and as a result am now getting these reference errors.

I may simply be overlooking something, but I cannot find it.

Errors:

```
Producers_Consumers.c:52: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’
/tmp/cceeOM6F.o: In function `producer':
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `sem_init'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x3a): undefined reference to `sem_init'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to `sem_post'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x6a): undefined reference to `sem_post'
/tmp/cceeOM6F.o: In function `consumer':
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x8a): undefined reference to `sem_wait'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0x96): undefined reference to `sem_post'
Producers_Consumers.c:(.text+0xa2): undefined reference to `sem_post'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I have (It may look a bit ugly due to the way I commented things out from my old method) I also know my adding method won't work, but I'll get to that when I fix my syntax issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define N 10     //Number of slots in buffer
typedef int semaphore;  //Semaphores ae a special kind of int
sem_t mutex; //Controls access to critical region 1
sem_t empty;  //Counts empty buffer slots N
sem_t  full;  //Counts full buffer slots 0
int count = 0; //What we're putting in 
//int buffer[N];

void producer(void) {
    sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
    //sem_init(&empty, 0, N);
    sem_init(&full, 0, 0);

    while(1) { 
        sem_wait(&empty);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        //printf("Empy: %d\n",empty);
        //printf("Mutex: %d\n",mutex);
        //printf("Both Downs Ran\n");
        //buffer = buffer + 1;
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&full);
        //printf("Producer produced: %d\n",buffer);
    }
}

void consumer(void) {
    while(1) { 
        sem_wait(&full);
        sem_wait(&mutex);
        //item = buffer;
        sem_post(&mutex);
        sem_post(&empty);
        //printf("Consumer consumed: %d/n",item);
    }
}

void main() {

}
```

Comment: Can you post exact errors?

Comment: Updated original post with errors copied from terminal.

Answer (score 29):

If you are on a linux system, you'll need to compile and link with the `-pthread` flag to link the pthreads library.

```
gcc -pthread Producers_Consumers.c
```

As Paul Griffiths has pointed out, you can also use `-lrt`, which is more portable, and links the POSIX Realtime Extensions library

```
gcc Producers_Consumers.c -lrt
```

---

Other notes specific to the code in the question:

- `int main(void)` not `void main()`
- `typedef int semaphore` is wrong, `sem_t` should be treated as an opaque type, you never use this typedef in your code anyway.
- A problem I foresee is that your `consumer` code uses the semaphores before they are initialized in `producer`.  You should initialize them in your `main`

Comment: You may need `-lrt`, and the libraries should go after the `.c` file.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I knew I was overlooking something simple. This solved my original issue. Thanks!

As for the main... I know, I was experimenting and forgot to change it back!

Comment: @PaulGriffiths thanks, updated.  For reader's reference, `-pthread` isn't the same as the linked command `-lpthread`, and does a bit more, which is why it doesn't have to follow the `c` files

Comment: I've tried `-lrt`, `-lpthread`, and `-pthread` because every source I read cites something different, and none of them work.  The command is `gcc -c ./src/server.c -lrt/pthread/lpthread`

Comment: @RyanHaining Sorry it got fixed.  I wasn't following the gcc ordering of args and files

Answer (score 4):

Got same error in ubuntu qt.
After adding

> LIBS += -lpthread -lrt

to project.pro file all compiled fine.